# Firebase crashlytics: Non-registered testers sign up

Tags: firebase

I am using **Firebase Crashlytics** in my Android app. At this point, my app is exclusively available as an **internal test version** which is only visible to 3 known testers (set up within Google Play console). Everything works well and I see my crashs in the console.

**However, I keep getting crash resports of totally unknown users who are not registered as testers.** I can see these users in the Authentication tab in the Firebase console. Here is a snippet:

[image]

I see crash reports of **totally unknown devices** which definitely do not belong to any of my registered testers. They are definitely not coming from an emulator.

**QUESTION:** Does anyone have an idea where these users come from and how they can access an app in the internal test track?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, if anyone has the same question: I got this answer [here](https://firebase.community/):

**Google/Android runs some automated bot tests on your app.**

Would be great if that were documented somewhere...